# Cannot rename a war or jar file on a maven deploy github actions

Tags: maven, github, jar, war, github-actions

When I try to deploy a war or jar file with github actions I can't rename the war/jar file to what I want; I tried changing the name using finalName tag but that didn't work it seems when I install it before hand it gives it the proper name, however when it deploys the name defaults back to artifactId-version, is their a maven commmand that I can put into github actions in order to fix this?

here is the build tag section of my pom file I do have another build tag at the beginning of this code sample, stack overflow isn't showing it for some reason

```
    <sourceDirectory>WEB-INF/src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>            
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                 <webXml>WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>    
                 

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
             <execution>
                <id>tomcat-run</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- optional only if you want to use a preconfigured server.xml file -->
                    <!-- <serverXml>src/main/tomcatconf/server.xml</serverXml> -->
                    <warRunDependencies>
                        <warRunDependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>a groupId</groupId>
                                <artifactId>and artifactId</artifactId>
                                <version>version</version>
                                <type>war</type>
                            </dependency>
                            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                        </warRunDependency>
                    </warRunDependencies>
                    <!-- naming is disabled by default so use true to enable it -->
                    <enableNaming>true</enableNaming>
                    <!-- extra dependencies to add jdbc driver, mail jars, etc. -->
                    <extraDependencies>
                        <extraDependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                            <version>10.1.3.1</version>
                        </extraDependency>
                        <extraDependency>
                            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4</version>
                        </extraDependency>
                    </extraDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Simple answer is: No you can't. The naming is based on fixed rules. If a name could be changed no one else could not ever use the usage via coordinates.

Comment: Is your maven project a spring boot ?

Comment: so km even if I use the finalName tag inside of build in a pom file I can't change the name of the jar/war?

Comment: The name can only be changed for the `target` directory but not for a deployment...

Answer (score -1):

### Note

All depends of your pom.xml. If you are using custom plugins related to the artifact final name, it would be complicated to override the final name.

### Simple Jar (maven solution)

Jar is usually used for libraries and standalone apps. After spring-boot, is used for server side apps.

According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39407739/3957754 you can override the final jar name with:

```
mvn clean package -Djar.finalName=acmejar
```

I tested with [this](https://github.com/jrichardsz/java-snippets/tree/master/hello-world-jar) simple code and it works!

And then in your yml:

```
name: Java CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean package -Djar.finalName=acmejar verify
```

Some frameworks with custom maven configurations may cause this method to not work. In that case, use some of these approaches to override the jar name using maven:

[How to override maven property in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876165/how-to-override-maven-property-in-command-line)

### War, spring-boot, etc (maven solution)

As I said, maven projects with complex plugins, needs special treatment in order to override the final artifact name.

The probed solution is to execute some operations after everything else finishes. I used [Apache Maven AntRun Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)

If I run `mvn clean package` in [this](https://github.com/jrichardsz/java-snippets/tree/master/hello-world-web-jersey) repository, the generated war is: **jersey-simple-1.0.0.war**

[image: img1]

But if I add this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war" 
                        tofile="${project.build.directory}/${newName}.war"/>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And run this: `mvn clean package -DnewName=foo`

A new war name is generated:

[image: img2]

You could use the [move task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) if you don't need to have the initial file:

```
<move file="file.orig" tofile="file.moved"/>
```

Finally add this line to your github action yml.

[This](https://github.com/jrichardsz/java-snippets/tree/master/maven-override-war-name) is the repository with the ant run plugin.

### Pure unix commands

You can run basic [unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62436968/3957754) commands in Github Actions.

So if you know the initial name after the success `mvn clean package`, you could use the `mv` command to rename it:

```
jobs:
  docit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: rename war
      run: |
        mv "${dirname}/original.war" "${dirname}/newName.war"
```

Comment: This given example has some issues. Using `clean package .. verify` run a lot of phases twice.. it's sufficient `mvn clean verify`... because `package` is part of the life cycle (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: The maven-jar-plugin does not support a property `jar.finalName`(https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) apart from that it would only change the name in `target` directory but not if do `mvn install` or `mvn deploy`..

Comment: another thing to mention km is that I was able to do version:set -DnewVersion command during the deploy line of my github actions however, that only put a datetime at the end of the jar/war name

Comment: I tried with a real maven project and worked. Attach your pom.xml to the question

Comment: JRichardsz what did you do to make it work? I need it to be done using git actions however, was their something that you added to your pom file to make it work cause I could change my pom file around, I'll attach the build tag section of my pom file to the question